# Restriction of Measure to complemet set

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I'm having trouble showing the following

Let $g$ be a measurable function on $\Omega$ and $Q, Q_k$ be a probability measure on $\Omega$.If $U$ is a measurable set such that $Q(U) = 0$ and $Q_k(U)$ is maximum and the measures $Q'$ and $Q'_k$ are the restriction of $Q$ ( and $Q'$) respectively to $\Omega \setminus U$, then $Q'_k$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $Q'$.

I'm having trouble showing the above statement, along with the fact that such $U$ exists